# How to determine the sequence of events fired on adding file to a SharePoint 2007 document library?

Tags: development, document

Let's add some how-tos on what happens.

Comment: if you want a knowledgebase entry you should mark this post as community wiki

Comment: done. community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default (out-of-the-box, with only your receiver running) sequence is ItemUpdating (no filename, id=0), ItemAdding (filename present, id=0), ItemAdded (filename present, id>0).

To determine the sequence for other actions, create a feature using Visual Studio with VSeWSS (which will handily generate all method stubs and register the receiver for you) or a feature with receiver using [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com) and add calls to a private method that would contain logging logic (to log to a list called 'log' with a text field called 'info') like the following:

```
    private static void LogEventToSPList(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        // 'using' clauses properly dispose of SPSite and SPWeb upon completion.
        using (SPSite s = new SPSite("http://sharepoint"))
        {
            using (SPWeb w = s.RootWeb)
            {
                SPListItem newitem = w.Lists["log"].Items.Add();
                newitem["info"] = string.Format(
                "At {0} {1} occurred on item with ID {2} " +
                "(at url {3}) properties changed "
                +"on behalf of {6} in the list called '{7}' " +
                "changing {4}/{5} properties.", 
                DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
                properties.EventType.ToString(),
                properties.ListItemId.ToString(),
                string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                      properties.WebUrl,
                      properties.RelativeWebUrl,
                      properties.AfterUrl), 
                properties.AfterProperties.ChangedProperties.Count,
                properties.BeforeProperties.ChangedProperties.Count,
                properties.UserLoginName,
                properties.ListTitle);
                newitem.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer is complicated by different ways you can add documents and what events are associated to the files being added. Check event troubleshooting guide here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979520.aspx